# SQLContext object has no attribute read while reading csv in pyspark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I am loading a csv file into pyspark as follows (within pyspark shell):

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>>> sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
>>> df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('data.csv')
```

but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SQLContext' object has no attribute 'read'
>>>
```

I am using spark 1.3.1 and I am trying to use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to use `Spark 1.4+` syntax.

For [Spark **1.3**](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#python-api)

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.load(source="com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true", path = "cars.csv")
df.select("year", "model").save("newcars.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

Comment: Actually I am using the python api example of the spark-csv module, https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#python-api. which makes use of read as I am doing

Comment: @MedAli you are trying to use `Spark 1.4+:` syntax